# pymongo is not closing connections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

we are trying to make an api server for our project.

we are using mongodb with pymongo on debian boxes. everyhting is up to
date.

but we are having a really weird connection problem. there is
generally more than 15k-32k connections to mongodb port when i check
with

root@webserver1:/#  netstat -na | grep mongo_db_ip | wc -l

i got 15363

connections are at TIME_WAIT state...

but when i check mongo, i only see 5-6 connections at the moment...

we wrote a mongodb class, that creates an instance and makes
connection. we tried call conn.disconnect() or conn.end_request()
everytime query end but it is not stoped that high connection
number...

is there anybody can tell what should be my mistake, or is there any
written python class for mongodb to examine how others make such as
stuff...

thanks for help, and information...

Comment: You might want to checkout connection pooling or bit.ly's asyncmongo instead of making a new connection with every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIME_WAIT is not an open connection. It's an Operating System state for a socket so that it can make sure all data has come through. AFAIK, the default length for this on Linux is a minute. Have a look at http://antmeetspenguin.blogspot.com/2008/10/timewait-in-netstat.html, it has a good explanation. You can tell the kernel to reuse the TIME_WAIT sockets though:

```
echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

reduces it to 30 seconds.

However, you should be checking why you are making so many connections. You're saying you're using the Debian packages for mongod and pymongo, and they tend to be out of date. You really want to be running mongod 2.0.2 and pymongo 2.1.1.

Comment: I don't think changing tcp_fin_timeout will affect TIME_WAIT timeout. For some reason in Linux this value is hard-coded into the kernel (2 minutes I I think) and cannot be changed dynamically.